# ¿Cómo guardar una cantidad para sumarla y restarla?

Tags: java, poo, object, objeto

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio de POO en el que tengo una cuenta bancaria con un saldo inicial de 0 euros, tengo dos variables numcuenta y saldo, en el que en el main voy a preguntar al usuario su numero de cuenta y con un scanner se añade al objeto la cuenta introducida, después en el objeto debo crear un metodo para conseguir el saldo ( puedo suponer que es un set y get)el saldo puede ser negativo y otros dos metodos uno para ingresar dinero llamado imposicion() y otro para retirar el dinero de nuestra cuenta llamado reintegro().

Tengo este codigo:

**Main**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce tu cuenta corriente:");
    String nomCuenta = lector.next();

    CuentaCorriente usuario = new CuentaCorriente(nomCuenta,0);


    System.out.println("La cuenta corriente "+usuario.getNumCuenta()+" tiene: "
            + usuario.getSaldo()+" Euros de Saldo");

    System.out.println("Quieres ingresar dinero? (si/no)");
    String aceptar = lector.next();

    if (aceptar == "si" || aceptar == "SI" || aceptar == "Si" ) {
        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad a ingresar:");
        int insertar = lector.nextInt();
        System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.imposicion()+" Euros de saldo");

        System.out.println("Quieres retirar dinero? (si/no)");
        String aceptarRetiro = lector.next();

        if (aceptarRetiro == "si" || aceptarRetiro == "SI" || aceptarRetiro == "Si" ) {
            System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            int retirar = lector.nextInt();

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.reintegro()+" Euros de saldo");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Muchas gracias! Que tengas un buen dia!");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Quieres retirar dinero? (si/no)");
        String aceptarRetiro = lector.next();

        if (aceptarRetiro == "si" || aceptarRetiro == "SI" || aceptarRetiro == "Si" ) {
            System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            int retirar = lector.nextInt();

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.reintegro()+" Euros de saldo");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Muchas gracias! Que tengas un buen dia!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Tiene un problema, al introducir Si, SI o si no me funciona correctamente y ahora mismo no logro ver el porque.

**Objeto**

```
public class CuentaCorriente {

//variables
private String numCuenta;
private int saldo;

//constructor
public CuentaCorriente(String numCuenta, int saldo) {
    this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}


//getters y setters
public String getNumCuenta() {
    return numCuenta;
}

public void setNumCuenta(String numCuenta) {
    this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
}

public int getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}

public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}

//metodos
public int imposicion() {
    int saldoTotal=0;
    saldoTotal=this.saldo++;
    return saldoTotal;
}

public int reintegro() {
    int saldoTotal=0;
    saldoTotal=this.saldo--;
    return saldoTotal;      
}
}
```

Como logro que al saldo inicial 0 le sume o le reste el valor guardado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado tu error y también he modificado un par de cosas en tu código que se podían mejorar. También tenias los métodos de ingresar y retirar dinero mal hechos, no hacían su función.

Clase `CuentaCorriente`:

```
public class CuentaCorriente {

    //variables
    private String numCuenta;
    private int saldo;

    //constructor
    public CuentaCorriente(String numCuenta) {
        this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
        this.saldo = 0;
    }


    //getters y setters
    public String getNumCuenta() {
        return numCuenta;
    }

    public void setNumCuenta(String numCuenta) {
        this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
    }

    public int getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    //metodos
    public void imposicion(int cifra) {

        this.saldo = this.saldo + cifra;
    }

    public void reintegro(int cifra) {

        this.saldo = this.saldo - cifra;

    }
}
```

En esta clase he hecho funcional los métodos antes mencionados, y he cambiado un poco el constructor. El constructor ahora solo pide el numero de la cuenta, y por defecto deja el saldo a 0, así no tienes que introducir dos parámetros en el `Main`.

Clase `Main`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce tu cuenta corriente:");
    String nomCuenta = lector.next();

    CuentaCorriente usuario = new CuentaCorriente(nomCuenta);


    System.out.println("La cuenta corriente "+usuario.getNumCuenta()+" tiene: "
            + usuario.getSaldo()+" Euros de Saldo");

    System.out.println("Quieres ingresar dinero? (si/no)");
    String aceptar = lector.next();

    if (aceptar.equalsIgnoreCase("SI")) {

        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad a ingresar:");
        int insertar = lector.nextInt();

        usuario.imposicion(insertar);

        System.out.println("El saldo actual es: "+ usuario.getSaldo() +" Euros de saldo");

        System.out.println("Quieres retirar dinero? (si/no)");
        String aceptarRetiro = lector.next();

        if (aceptarRetiro.equalsIgnoreCase("SI")) {

            System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            int retirar = lector.nextInt();

            usuario.reintegro(retirar);

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+ usuario.getSaldo() +" Euros de saldo");
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Muchas gracias! Que tengas un buen dia!");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Quieres retirar dinero? (si/no)");
        String aceptarRetiro = lector.next();

        if (aceptarRetiro.equalsIgnoreCase("Si")) {
            System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            int retirar = lector.nextInt();

            usuario.reintegro(retirar);

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es: "+usuario.getSaldo()+" Euros de saldo");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Muchas gracias! Que tengas un buen dia!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Si introduces en el `if` un: `equalsIgnoreCase` va a comparar lo que introduce el usuario con una cadena, dando igual si esta en mayúsculas o minúsculas. Por lo tanto, te ahorrar tantas comparaciones dentro del `if`.

Y ahora cuando quieres mostrar el saldo que tiene la cuenta, en el `System.out.print()`, estas llamando al `get()` de la clase Cuenta que para eso esta. Y los dos metodos que realizan las funciones de ingresar o retirar, los vuelves `void` ya que no devuelven nada, solo hacen eso: restar o sumar.

Comment: Por cierto, te recomiendo que cambies el tipo de dato `int` a `double` o `float`. Ya que el saldo puede tener decimales. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola!! muchisimas gracias!! Ya comprendo al pasarle cifra le estamos pasando el saldo del main verdad? si resto saldo menos la cantidad extraida nos da el resultado de la resta igual con la suma del ingreso, para el if yo sabia que habia un modo pero no lograba dar con el gracias!!! claro tiene sentido yo quiero devolver el saldo no la operacion, muchisimas gracias me has ayudado un montón!!!!

Comment: Por cierto he cambiado el codigo y lo he puesto en double ya que tiene mucho sentido añadir decimales como centimos y esas cosas. Millones de gracias!

Comment: De nada!. Me alegra que te solucione el error y de paso hayas aprendido un par de cosas :)

Comment: PD: Aparte de por aquí, me gusta ayudar a los que estan comenzando y los que no, si alguna vez necesitas alguna respuesta rápida, estoy por Discord para todos: Youshiro#4002

Comment: Muchísimas gracias luego te agrego :) Soy un mar de dudas ( T_T xD) , aunque prometo no molestar mucho :)

Answer (score 0):

Revisé tu ejercicio e hice unas modificaciones, que te explicaré a continuación:
en tus métodos de imposición y reintegro tenías esto:

```
public int imposicion() {
    int saldoTotal=0;
    saldoTotal=this.saldo++;
    return saldoTotal;
}
```

esto siempre te va a devolver 0, ya que el valor de ambos valores es 0,entonces... `0+0=0`.
lo que yo hice, para empezar, cambié tus variables int por double, ya que como hablamos de monedas, pueden exisitir decimales, así que es conveniente usar un tipo de dato que pueda manejar decimales (también los inicialicé por cualquier cosa). en segunda, hice que tu método reciba el valor que ingresas en el programa, para que lo agregue a tu variable `saldo`. ambos métodos, (imposición y reintegro) quedaron así:

```
public Double imposicion(Double insertar) {
    this.saldo+=insertar;
    return this.saldo;
}

public Double reintegro(Double retirar) {
    this.saldo-=retirar;
    return this.saldo;      
}
```

ahora, en tu programa, veo que al poner "si" en las opciones no lo respetaba, así que hice lo siguiente:
en tu escaner, hago a propósito que lo que te escriban llegue siempre en minúsculas, quedando la línea así:

```
String aceptarRetiro = lector.next().toLowerCase();
```

el método toLowerCase(); hace que si tu ingresas "SI", "Si", "sI" o lo que sea, siempre lo devolverá en minúsculas. sabiendo eso, tu string lo comparo usando equals:

```
if ("si".equals(aceptarRetiro)) {
       //contenido del método
}
```

para usar los métodos de imposición y reintegro necesitas pasarle entre los paréntesis un double, que ya lo estamos obteniendo el scanner, y queda así:

```
System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            Double retirar = lector.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.reintegro(retirar)+" Euros de saldo");
```

En general, tu clase queda así:

```
public class CuentaCorriente {
   //variables
private String numCuenta="";
private Double saldo=0.0;

//constructor
public CuentaCorriente(String numCuenta, Double saldo) {
    this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}


//getters y setters
public String getNumCuenta() {
    return numCuenta;
}

public void setNumCuenta(String numCuenta) {
    this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
}

public Double getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}

public void setSaldo(Double saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}

//metodos
public Double imposicion(Double insertar) {
    this.saldo+=insertar;
    return this.saldo;
}

public Double reintegro(Double retirar) {
    this.saldo-=retirar;
    return this.saldo;      
} 
}
```

tu método main:

```
Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce tu cuenta corriente:");
    String nomCuenta = lector.next();

    CuentaCorriente usuario = new CuentaCorriente(nomCuenta,0.0);


    System.out.println("La cuenta corriente "+usuario.getNumCuenta()+" tiene: "
            + usuario.getSaldo()+" Euros de Saldo");

    System.out.println("Quieres ingresar dinero? (si/no)");
    String aceptar = lector.next().toLowerCase();

    if ("si".equals(aceptar)) {
        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad a ingresar:");
        Double insertar = lector.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.imposicion(insertar)+" Euros de saldo");

        System.out.println("Quieres retirar dinero? (si/no)");
        String aceptarRetiro = lector.next().toLowerCase();

        if ("si".equals(aceptarRetiro)) {
            System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            Double retirar = lector.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.reintegro(retirar)+" Euros de saldo");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Muchas gracias! Que tengas un buen dia!");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Quieres retirar dinero? (si/no)");
        String aceptarRetiro = lector.next();

        if (aceptarRetiro == "si" || aceptarRetiro == "SI" || aceptarRetiro == "Si" ) {
            System.out.println("Que cantidad deseas retirar?");
            Double retirar = lector.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("El saldo actual es:"+usuario.reintegro(retirar)+" Euros de saldo");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Muchas gracias! Que tengas un buen dia!");
        }
    }
    }
```

espero haberme explicado bien, si no es el caso, pregúntame y con gusto te ayudo, saludos! :D